# Read data from Excel and write to Docx file using java

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx4j

I have some records with header in my excel sheet.I want to read all the records and write to the docx file along with header using java.Thanks for the helps.
Able to write one excel to other excel file but failed to write in docx file.
I have try this way but the word file is generated as corrupted.

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class ExcelReaderDemo {
public static final String SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH = 
   "C:/XLXSToDocx/Roaster.xlsm";
public static final String FILE_PATH ="C:/XLXSToDocx/writeExcel.docx";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, 
InvalidFormatException {
    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new 
File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH));

    System.out.println("Workbook has " + workbook.getNumberOfSheets() + " 
Sheets : ");

    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
            System.out.print(cellValue + "\t");
        }

        try {

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(FILE_PATH);

            workbook.write(fos);

            fos.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        System.out.println();
    }
    workbook.close();
}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried so far.

Comment: updated my post..@Web

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Apache Poi lib (https://poi.apache.org/)

Comment: I have tried using Apache Poi as you can see my sample code above.

Comment: Can you try `XSSFWorkbook` instead of Workbook?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public class ExcelReaderDemo {
    public static final String SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH = "C:/XLXSToDocx/Roaster.xlsm";
    public static final String FILE_PATH = "C:/XLXSToDocx/writeExcel.docx";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH));

        System.out.println("Workbook has " + workbook.getNumberOfSheets() + " Sheets : ");

        try {

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(FILE_PATH);

            workbook.write(fos);

            fos.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        System.out.println("DONE !!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.The docx file is generated as corrupted.I can't open the docx file.